# Service discovery in Micronaut if I have to call another microservice with a low-level HTTP client using reactor-netty

Tags: java, micronaut, service-discovery, reactor-netty

I need to call another microservice already registered in Consul. But I can't use the Micronaut HTTP Client either the RxJava HTTP client. I need to discover the URL of that microservice to call it. Therefore, I think, I can't use @client annotation to specify the name of the service that I want to discover its URL. Please, give me an example of how can I use reactor-netty to call another microservice and could discover its URL which already registered in Consul.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by injecting the Consul Client and calling "getInstances" function his.

```
package happy.shopping.apigw.infrastructure.client.rest.reports;

import io.micronaut.discovery.ServiceInstance;
import io.micronaut.discovery.consul.client.v1.ConsulClient;
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static reactor.adapter.rxjava.RxJava2Adapter.singleToMono;

@Singleton
public class ReportClient {
    private static final Logger logger
            = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportClient.class);
    @Inject
    ConsulClient consulClient;

    public Mono<List<ServiceInstance>> getInstances() {
        Single<List<List<ServiceInstance>>> listaDeInstancias =  Flowable.fromPublisher(consulClient.getInstances("ms-reports")).toList();
        Single<List<ServiceInstance>> instanciasAplanadas = listaDeInstancias.map(this::flattenListOfListsStream);
        return singleToMono(instanciasAplanadas);
    }

    public <T> List<T> flattenListOfListsStream(@NotNull List<List<T>> list) {
        return list.stream()
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public Mono<Optional<String>> chooseAnInstance(){
        Mono<List<ServiceInstance>> instances = getInstances();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return instances.map(listOfInstances -> {
            if (listOfInstances.size() > 0) {
                int instanceIndex = rnd.nextInt(listOfInstances.size());
                return Optional.ofNullable(listOfInstances.get(instanceIndex).getURI().toString());
            }else {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        });
    }



}
```

function "chooseAnInstance" returns an URL of one of the instances and I use that to call the other microservice' API. Function "chooseAnInstance" chooses one random instance.